# Bar chart with Number XAxis (Distribution chart) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, charts, bar-chart

I am new to JavaFX. I want to make a chart that visualizes the distribution of events throughout time, I found many Bar charts tutorials but they all use a String as their XAxis.

```
final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
final BarChart<String, Number> bc= new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
```

I want to use an Number as XAxis instead, because I have a value associated for each timestamp.

My final visualization should look like this:

[image]

How can I adapt Bar chart to do this?

Comment: JavaFx charts can do this out of the box. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

Comment: That's just a bar chart.